# Asking Numpy. Why i can get result this?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading the book Introduction Machine Learning to Python and this code is on page 69.
I can't understand that why I can get a result of this.

```
X = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

for label in np.unique(y):
    print(X[y == label])
```

result:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: what were you expecting to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down piece by piece.

1. `np.unique(y)`

   `np.unique` returns all of the unique elements of the given array. In this case, that's `[0, 1]` (since there are only two unique elements in `y`, 0 and 1).

   So running

   ```py
   for label in np.unique(y):
   ```

   will iterate twice. The first time `label` will equal `0`, and the second time it will equal `1`. You can inspect this for yourself by running

   ```py
   for label in np.unique(y):
       print(label)
   ```
2. `y == label`

   If you run a comparison against an array, numpy will return a boolean array of the same size. So on the first iteration of the `for` loop, it'll be running `y == 0`, which gives us `[ True False  True False]`, since the first and third element in `y` are 1. Then on the second iteration, it'll be running `y == 1`, giving us the inverse, `[False  True False  True]`.

   You can inspect this for yourself by running:

   ```py
   for label in np.unique(y):
       print(y == label)
   ```
3. `X[y == label]`

   Now that we know what the rest of the logic is doing, the last piece is determining what happens when passing the `y == label` as a "selector" for elements in `X`. When you pass a boolean array as a selector, you're telling numpy which elements of the original array you want to return. In this case, `X`  is a 2-dimensional array (size 4x4), and if we pass an array of length 4, we're telling numpy which *rows* we want to select.

   As mentioned above, on the first iteration `y == label` is `[ True False  True False]`, so we're saying we want the first and third rows of X. So `print(X[y == label])` gives

   ```
   [[0 1 0 1]
    [0 0 0 1]]
   ```

   And then on the second iteration, per the above, `y == label` will be selecting the second and fourth rows, giving:

   ```
   [[1 0 1 1]
    [1 0 1 0]]
   ```

Hope that clarifies!

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: #3     X[y == label]

With X[[True, False, True, False]] how you can obtain the first and third rows of X.
You can explain?

Comment: The array `[True, False, True, False]` is choosing which rows of `X` based on which indexes are True. Since the first and third elements of the array are `True` (and others are `False`), you're telling numpy you want to select the first and third rows of `X`. So for example, if you instead passed in `[False, False, True, False]`, you'd be selecting only the third row of X, since only the third index is `True`.